# About testing the iCloud synchronisation

Tags: ios, icloud

I have an application which is using iCloud to synchronise the NSUserDefault data. The app is distributed to app store already. But I need to do some tests for the iCloud synchronisation functions when I develop the new version. My question is if the version in my Xcode (debug version using development profile) is using the same iCloud as the one in production? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should use the iCloud account your test device is logged into. I tend to use a second iCloud account for testing just to make sure I don't mess up personal data I want to keep within my own apps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.So that means the same iCloud is used if I login with the same id no matter it's from production or testing app. Am I right?

Comment: Yup, it all depends on what you're logged in as on the device you're using for testing.